# ClientRegistration.Builder adds trailing "/" at the end of issuer uri. How to prevent that?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, openid, spring-security-oauth2

My application needs to be an API client, using Spring Security, Oauth 2.0, and OpenID, in Spring Boot.
My issuer URI for OpenID should not have a trailing "/", the API provider mentioned that in the documentation.

```
application.yaml

spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          IdOfMyApp:
            provider: https://api.provider.guys.com
            client-id: [my id here]
            client-secret: [my secret here]
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
            - pr.pro
            - pr.act
            - openid
            - offline
            redirect-uri: https://my.domain.com/fallback
            client-name: My App Name
        provider:
         IdOfProvider:
          authorization-uri: https://api.provider.guys.com/oauth2/auth
          token-uri: https://api.provider.guys.com/oauth2/token
          issuer-uri: https://api.provider.guys.com
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://api.provider.guys.com
logging:
  level:
    '[org.springframework.web]': DEBUG
```

so my issuer-uri is `https://api.provider.guys.com` (I made it up to be a placeholder for example, but real URI is similar).

When I go to the `ClientRegistration.Builder withProviderConfiguration(AuthorizationServerMetadata metadata, String issuer)` method in `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration` in debug mode, I've noticed that the metadata parameter has "https://api.provider.guys.com/" (with trailing /) and the issuer parameter has a value of "https://api.provider.guys.com".

```
private static ClientRegistration.Builder withProviderConfiguration(AuthorizationServerMetadata metadata,
        String issuer) {
    String metadataIssuer = metadata.getIssuer().getValue();
    Assert.state(issuer.equals(metadataIssuer),
            () -> "The Issuer \"" + metadataIssuer + "\" provided in the configuration metadata did "
                    + "not match the requested issuer \"" + issuer + "\"");
    String name = URI.create(issuer).getHost();
    ClientAuthenticationMethod method = getClientAuthenticationMethod(metadata.getTokenEndpointAuthMethods());
    Map<String, Object> configurationMetadata = new LinkedHashMap<>(metadata.toJSONObject());
    // @formatter:off
    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(name)
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(method)
            .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .authorizationUri((metadata.getAuthorizationEndpointURI() != null) ? metadata.getAuthorizationEndpointURI().toASCIIString() : null)
            .providerConfigurationMetadata(configurationMetadata)
            .tokenUri(metadata.getTokenEndpointURI().toASCIIString())
            .issuerUri(issuer)
            .clientName(issuer);
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Then this exception occurs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Issuer "https://api.provider.guys.com/" provided in the configuration metadata did not match the requested issuer "https://api.provider.guys.com"
```

My `OAuthClientConfiguration` class

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthClientConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository  clientRegistrations(
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.IdOfProvider.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.IdOfMyApp.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.IdOfMyApp.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.IdOfMyApp.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrantType,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.IdOfMyApp.redirect-uri}") String redirectUri,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.IdOfProvider.authorization-uri}") String authorizationUri,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.IdOfProvider.issuer-uri}") String issuerUri)
    {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("IdOfMyApp")
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .scope("pr.pro", "pr.act", "openid", "offline")
                .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(authorizationGrantType))
                .redirectUri(redirectUri)
                .authorizationUri(authorizationUri)
                .issuerUri(issuerUri)
                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }
    
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations)
    {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager  = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("IdOfMyApp");
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
}
```

How to prevent that "/" from appending to my issuer URI in `AuthorizationServerMetadata` object?