# Spring OAuth 401 exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I'm building a Spring Boot application with OAuth 2.0 and OpenID. Application is an API client. When the user opens the app, he is redirected to Authorization URI (that works). After login and permission grants, he should be redirected to a callback URI (that works).
Before the next page app should take some info from API, but I get `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized from GET https(URL of resource)`.

My `application yaml`.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          localhost-for-development-3:
            provider: spring
            client-id: myId
            client-secret:  mySecret
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope:
            - pr.pro
            - pr.act
            - openid
            - offline
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}
            client-name: localhost-for-development-3
        provider:
          spring:
            authorization-uri: https://someurl.com/oauth2/auth
            token-uri: https://someurl.com/oauth2/token
            issuer-uri: https://someurl.com/
logging:
  level:
    '[org.springframework.web]': DEBUG
```

OAuthClientConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
public class OAuthClientConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository  clientRegistrations(
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spring.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.localhost-for-development-3.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.localhost-for-development-3.client-secret}") String clientSecret,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.localhost-for-development-3.authorization-grant-type}") String authorizationGrantType,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.localhost-for-development-3.redirect-uri}") String redirectUri,
            @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spring.authorization-uri}") String authorizationUri
            )
//  @Value(value = "${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.spring.issuer-uri}") String issuerUri
    {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("localhost-for-development-3")
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .scope("m3p.f.pr.pro", "m3p.f.pr.act", "openid", "offline")
                .authorizationGrantType(new AuthorizationGrantType(authorizationGrantType))
                .redirectUri(redirectUri)
                .authorizationUri(authorizationUri)
//              .issuerUri(issuerUri)
//              .jwkSetUri("https://someurl.com")
                .build();
        
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }
    
    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations)
    {
        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations);
        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager  = new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService);
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("localhost-for-development-3");
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to look for in the Google console network tab. I see I got the "code" parameter. It's probably an authorization code. I don't see that I've received a token.

Please, if I need to provide you with more details, inform me what I need to look for, and I'll edit the question.

Also, the API provider mentioned that for issuer-uri I MUST write URL WITHOUT trailing "/" at the end. But when I do so, Spring Security will throw an exception. Is that connected to my problem maybe? I've already mentioned this problem in more detail in this post:

[ClientRegistration.Builder adds trailing "/" at the end of issuer uri. How to prevent that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72746922/clientregistration-builder-adds-trailing-at-the-end-of-issuer-uri-how-to-pr)